# Dynamic conditional formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to find solution for dynamic conditional formatting.

For when the range has a 'FALSE' cell, highlight the value 4 columns ahead.

Example =G4='FALSE' --> format C4 cell.

However, I cannot specify the columns as I wouldn't know which column will have a 'FALSE' cell.

But there is a baseline format. E.g. the whole range is a pattern of 7 columns. The 2nd column of the range will the value to be highlighted and the 6th column of the range will have True/False.

Is there a way to check every 6th column for FALSE cell and highlight the value 4 columns ahead.

Any suggestions?

[Below is a sample of how my excel looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86IV9.png)

Thank you xoxo

Comment: If you temporarily change to `R1C1` mode then you can use a relative reference to create your conditional formatting. You can always flip back to `A1` mode after it's set up. IMHO though, `R1C1` mode is much easier to work with in general and I leave mine in that mode all of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you wanting it to update as the values are entered? if so then you could use a the Worksheet_Change event, it's a bit crude but would work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Value = "False" Then
        With Target.Offset(0, -3).Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 5287936
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Need more details to assist you further, if you want something you can run on an as needs basis then it should be fairly trivial for you to convert this to a sub routine as opposed to an event, just poll through the used data.

Based on your comments, something like this will do what you want:

```
Sub Temp()
Dim X As Long
For X = 1 To Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Range("E" & X).Value = "False" Then
        With Range("E" & X).Offset(0, -3).Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 5287936
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Change `"E"` in both instances of the `Range` if you want it to poll another column.

Comment: I am new to VBA.this is the vba code below. When it runs, nothing happens. Kindly advise where I went wrong                                               
`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Value = "False" Then
        With Target.Offset(0, -3).Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 5287936
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub hello()
Run "sheet1.worksheet_change", Range("a1")
End Sub`

Comment: You cant fire a worksheet event from a subroutine. From the looks of it you need to put it into a sub routine in a module and run it on a range, the worksheet event code I posted was to make it automatically fire every time you entered something into column C but for that to happen, this code needs to be at the worksheet level, NOT in a module.

Comment: How can I set range to the entire sheet? I tried changing the "E" to the "A1" 3  times in the code but gives me error

Comment: Why on earth would you do the entire sheet? You want to find anywhere on the sheet that says "False" and shade three to the left green? Check out `activesheet.usedrange` and loop that instead of column E